# How to clip a background image using css without affecting its size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, clip

I'm using a picture I found on Google Images as a background image. However, a Google Search bar appears at its top. On its left hand side various icons/logs such as WhatsApp, Gmail etc...appears too. I've tried various css rules like, clip: rect(), background-position, background-clip to get rid of them so the user won't see them. But in vain so far. Just so there's no confusion I want the image to be smaller but still covering the background.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const intro = document.querySelector(".intro");
const quiz = document.querySelector(".quiz");
const introMessage = document.querySelector(".introMessage");
const quizImage = document.querySelector(".quizImage img");
console.log(quizImage.src)



let japaneseAnimeJapanese = [
{
  name: "ドラゴンボール",
  picture: "https://dbgbh.bn-ent.net/assets/img/news/news_thumb_kv.png"
},
{
  name: "進撃の巨人",
  picture: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJYjy_bS8t3ScWyG7q94fIltnar3ChaOHmGA&usqp=CAU"
},
{
  name: "ナルト",
  picture: "https://res.cloudinary.com/jerrick/image/upload/v1616592065/605b3cc118e784001e22da0d.jpg"
},
{
  name: "鬼滅の刃",
  picture: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gcVHhhZ4VwVswvbDPvI-RfQ7ECQ=/1400x1050/filters:format(png)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19721018/Tanjiro__Demon_Slayer_.png"
},
{
  name: "攻殻機動隊",
  picture: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8VBbI5HMki5cmjP_Gq0TdyA6VZn_0_fmkhg&usqp=CAU"
}
]

let japaneseAnimeEnglish = [
{
  name: "dragon ball",
  picture: "https://dbgbh.bn-ent.net/assets/img/news/news_thumb_kv.png"
},
{
  name: "Attack On Titans",
  picture: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJYjy_bS8t3ScWyG7q94fIltnar3ChaOHmGA&usqp=CAU"
},
{
  name: "naruto",
  picture: "https://res.cloudinary.com/jerrick/image/upload/v1616592065/605b3cc118e784001e22da0d.jpg"
},
{
  name: "Demon Slayer",
  picture: "https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gcVHhhZ4VwVswvbDPvI-RfQ7ECQ=/1400x1050/filters:format(png)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19721018/Tanjiro__Demon_Slayer_.png"
},
{
  name: "Ghost in the shell",
  picture: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8VBbI5HMki5cmjP_Gq0TdyA6VZn_0_fmkhg&usqp=CAU"
}
]

select.addEventListener("change", displayButton);
button.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

function displayButton() {
  button.style.display = "block"
  introMessage.style.display = "none"
}

function startQuiz() {
  button.style.display = "none";
  quiz.style.display = "flex";
  intro.style.display = "none";
  quizImage.src = japaneseAnimeEnglish[0].picture

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("images/backgroundImage.jpeg");
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* clip: rect(0px,25px,25px,0px); */
  padding: 10px;
  background-position: 200%, 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;

}

.rule {
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;

}

.introMessage {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}

.quiz {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;

  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
}

.quizImage {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.multipleChoice {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.choice {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(97, 99, 90);
  color: white;
}

.choice:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background: rgb(77, 120, 66);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="intro">
      <h1 class="introMessage">Welcome to the anime quiz! Select a language and get started</h1>
      <select class="" name="">
        <option value="">Select a  language</option>
        <option value="">English</option>
        <option value="">日本語</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" name="button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz">
      <div class="quizImage">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="multipleChoice">
        <div class="choice">Choices1</div>
        <div class="choice">Choices2</div>
        <div class="choice">Choices3</div>
        <div class="choice">Choices4</div>
        <div class="choice">Choices5</div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="rule">Select answer corresponding to the image</h1>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  If you clip (or crop) an image then it will become smaller. Do you mean clip the image, but have the smaller image still cover the background? See: [MDN - background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I've amended my question accordingly.

Comment: Cant u just open the image on any image editor and crop it?

Comment: Do the removal of `height: 100%;` css rule on `img` provides the behavior you need?

Comment: The removal of height: 100%; css rule on img doesn't  provides the behavior I need.